# How do you save a DATE field in Firebase using AngularFire

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have a screen with a DATE field (Start Date) where the user can enter any date

```
<label class="item item-input">
     <span class="input-label">Start Date</span>
     <input type="date" ng-model="currentItem.OpenDate">
</label>
```

I added the following to the Save button's click event

```
console.log("Normal date " + $scope.currentItem.OpenDate);
```

The console shows the following date

```
Normal date Fri May 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Here's the push event

```
$scope.data.accounts.push({ 'AccountName': $scope.currentItem.AccountName, 'StartBalance': $scope.currentItem.StartBalance, 'OpenDate': $scope.currentItem.OpenDate, 'AccountType': $scope.currentItem.AccountType });
```

HOWEVER, the date `$scope.currentItem.OpenDate` is not getting saved to Firebase, the rest of the data is saving properly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You unfortunately didn't include the code that initializes the `OpenDate` property. But it looks like you're trying to write a JavaScript `Date` object into Firebase. The [Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html) specifies that it supports these types:

> object, array, string, number, boolean, or `null`

In order to store the `Date`'s value, you will have to convert it to a supported type. E.g.

```
$scope.data.accounts.push({ 
  'AccountName': $scope.currentItem.AccountName, 
  'StartBalance': $scope.currentItem.StartBalance, 
  'OpenDate': $scope.currentItem.OpenDate.toString(), 
  'AccountType': $scope.currentItem.AccountType 
});
```

Or alternatively:

```
  'OpenDate': $scope.currentItem.OpenDate.getTime(),
```

Comment: In general, `getTime()` is going to be more universal, easier to use with queries and sorting, and overall a more functional solution.

Comment: That worked for me. Thank you very much. Being a newbie is not fun sometimes, but gotta move forward!

Comment: @Kato Agreed, Im was searching for date range query.

Answer (score 14):

I just wanted to throw out a possibly more robust solution that may be useful to those who care about timezones.

I believe a valid solution is to store your dates as [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted strings. If you read the linked Wikipedia article, you will see that "The lexicographical order of the representation thus corresponds to chronological order, except for date representations involving negative years."

The Firebase docs state that ['Strings [...] are sorted lexicographically in ascending order.'](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data), so as long as you're dealing with positive years, you will be able to do advanced time searches while maintaining timezone info.

Comment: Awesome. Your answer leverages readability and functionality, instead of sacrificing readability as Frank suggested!