# How to initialize a date element to initialize model in Firebase/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

I need to manipulate each $firebasearray element to convert a date field ( saved as strings 'YYYYMMDD' ) in dates to expose then on the view at the corresponding tag :

```
<td width="7%"><input type="date" class="form-control"  ng-model="p.myDate"></td>
```

In this case the line above is inside an ng-repeat with the "p" elements from the array.I can't assign directly an string containing my date ( formated as 'YYYYMMDD' ) to the date field. It's necessary convert it to a date previously.

How ?

Comment: Firebase stores JSON data, and date values are not a known type there. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021133/how-do-you-save-a-date-field-in-firebase-using-angularfire

Comment: I know that...this is why I'm saving dates as strings.

Comment: The snippet above does not save it as a string. If you do the conversion somewhere, add that code too. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Add the moment.js library to your project. If the p.myDate is a date string, and you want a date object, try using this.

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.yourArray.length; i++) {
   if(moment($scope.yourArray[i].myDate).isValid()) {
     //if you want to keep the date string
     //$scope.yourArray[i].myDateString = $scope.yourArray[i].myDate;
     $scope.yourArray[i].myDate = new Date(moment($scope.yourArray[i].myDate));
   }
   else {
     console.log("not a valid date", $scope.yourArray[i].myDate);
   }
}
```

If there are no spaces, / or - between YYYY, MM and DD you should reformat the string. Let me know if this is the case and you need help with that.

Comment: Hi, interesting approach.
The conversion was ok and the date at the array was correctly converted from 'YYYYMMDD' to 'dd/MM/YYYY' but the INPUT expects a date object and then I have this error : angular.js:12520 Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `03/01/2016` to be a date ...

Comment: try replacing $scope.yourArray[i].myDate = moment($scope.yourArray[i].myDate); with $scope.yourArray[i].myDate = new Date(moment($scope.yourArray[i].myDate));